# Complex search query in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to React Native and Firebase and I am building an app using firestore.

the structure of firestore db looks like this :

AllPosts > Doc(each post) > Field(name,desc, .... , userId="12345")

and for users

users > doc(each user) id 12345 > field(name,desc,etc)

I don't know if this is the best way to setup the database. But when I go to a post screen, I need to load all data for that post & data for the userId who created the post, yet they are in entirely different collections.

I couldn't find a good way to do this.
I've tried setting the userId field from post doc to a const 'fetchUserById' and perform a query based on that, but I think it's dead wrong

```
    const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

        useEffect(() => {
    
            firebase.firestore()
            .collection("allPosts")
            .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data }
                })
                setPost(data)
            })

            const fetchUserById = post.userId;

            firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .where(fetchUserById, '==', firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.exists) {
                    setUser(snapshot.data());
                }
                else {
                    
                }
            })
           
            
    
        },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

since you store document id in `post.userId` you can just select document directly by id like that:

```js
 firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(post.userId)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.exists) {
                    setUser(snapshot.data());
                }
                else {
                    
                }
            })
```

---

the reason you are getting `undefined is not an object` is because `post` is not yet set within this execution of the `useEffect`. The flow is following:

1. Component render method is called
2. post is set to default value of `[]` (it seems that you do not expect a collection of posts so it should probably not be [])
3. `useEffect()` callback is called
4. you fetch `allPosts` from from firestore
5. you call `setPost(data)`

   - this triggers state update and component is re-rendered
6. in the re-rendered component the `post` variable is now set to collection of posts but in the `useEffect()` callback which is still running the `post` variable is still the same (empty array).
7. fetching user fails because `post.userId` is undefined

You have multiple options how to solve it:

1. you can store `post.userId` in a local variable inside of the `useEffect()` callback
2. you can have a separate `useEffect` with dependency on post.

I like the first approach better, you should also not use `where` condition when you need a single document by id. Overall your code should be like that (I think, don't have anywhere to test it right now):

```js
const [post, setPost] = useState(null); // you don't need an array here. You get 1 post and 1 user for it.
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("allPosts")
        .doc(props.route.params.postId) // no need to use `where`
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            const postData =snapshot.data();
            setPost(postData) // getting single document, no need to iterate over results
            // you cannot fetch user before you know its id so your next query should be inside of `then` callback 
            firebase.firestore()
                    .collection('users')
                    .doc(postData.userId)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        if (snapshot.exists) {
                            setUser(snapshot.data());
                        }
                    })
        })
    },[props.route.params.postId]) // you probably want to re-fetch if postId changes
```

Comment: This sounds like a great solution, but It just keeps throwing error "undefined is not an object"

Answer (score 0):

If you know the document ID then you shouldn't use the `where` method.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users')
    .doc(props.route.params.postId)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
            setUser(snapshot.data());
        } else {
                    
        }
    })
```

The `get()` method returns a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

Same goes for the second query but just a note, first parameter in `.where()` is the field name or path you are looking for and the third parameter is the value.

```
@param fieldPath — The path to compare

@param opStr — The operation string (e.g "<", "<=", "==", ">", ">=").

@param value — The value for comparison
```

Comment: I don't think is going to work.As I said above, I have 2 separate collections, users and Allposts. In allPosts I have docs with all kind of fields, including a field "userId" for creator user. My goal, is to take the userId value from that field, and find a doc in firestore with name == to the userId path in allPosts collection